# Extensible ladder getting dragged away from a wall

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> An extensible ladder rests vertically against the side of a 10 foot wall. You start dragging the bottom of the ladder along the floor away from the wall at a  rate of 0.5 ft/sec. At the moment when the wall makes a 60 degree angle with the ladder, how fast is the distance between bottom and top of the ladder changing?

I'm unsure how to make my equation. I think I'm supposed to start with a trigonometry function, but I'm not sure how to start.

Answer (score 0):

First, make a diagram of the situation:

```
A
|\
| \
|  \
|   \
O----B
```

Here $OA=10$ and $OB=k$ is increasing at 0.5 per second. The length of the ladder $AB=L$ in terms of $k$ is, by the Pythagorean theorem:
$$L=\sqrt{k^2+100}$$
Taking derivatives:
$$\frac{dL}{dk}=\frac{2k}{2\sqrt{k^2+100}}=\frac k{\sqrt{k^2+100}}$$
We also know that
$$\frac{dk}{dt}=0.5$$
Multiplying the two derivatives together:
$$\frac{dL}{dt}=\frac{dL}{dk}\cdot\frac{dk}{dt}=\frac k{2\sqrt{k^2+100}}$$
When the angle betwen ladder and wall is 60 degrees, $k=10\tan60^\circ=10\sqrt3$ and hence
$$\frac{dL}{dt}=\frac{10\sqrt3}{2\sqrt{(10\sqrt3)^2+100}}=\frac{10\sqrt3}{2\cdot20}=\frac{\sqrt3}4$$
Hence the distance between the ladder's ends is increasing at around 0.433 feet per second at the given instant.